# The pinia state value changes while the muted props value changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

In my application, i used pinia store and event emit implementation to mutate props value from child component to parent component, but now both values are reactive. while I change my value from the parent component the child component data (pinia store value) also changes.

**Steps to reproduce the bug**
Provide the value from the store to the child component, and implement the event emits functionality to change the props (values from the parent) value to the store values (assign state value to props). Change the prop value in the parent component, and the store state value in the child component will be updated.

**Code**

```html
//Parent component
     <ChildComponent :values="computedValue" @setValue="(value)=> computedValue = value"/>

//Child component 
const store = servicesStore()
const value = store.getValue
<button @click="$emit('setValue', value)">

// Store
export const servicesStore = defineStore('services', {
    state: () => ({ 
        value: []
    }),
    getters: {
      getValue: (state) => { 
            return state.value
      }
    },
    actions: {
        async fetchvalue() {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(API_URL + '/value');
                this.value = response.data;
              } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
              }
        }
    },
})
//Note: fetchvalue() function will trigger when mounting the App.vue component
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @suneeth A reproducible example means that you need to provide code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask question updated with code , Thanks

Comment: It's unclear how it's supposed to work, the example is incomplete, there's no computedValue, it's unknown what happens what happens with `value` inside  ChildComponent. " while I change my value from the parent component" - nothing is changed in the code above Again https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is required. You've seen your own case, other users didn't. The question lacks clear problem statement, what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @EstusFlask i have fixed the issue, simply i just want to remove the reactivity of the pinia state value. Thanks

Comment: I see the answer. It's unclear where exactly it's needed. It looks like you mutate state where you shouldn't. You may need to clone a value at some point, this is what JSON.stringify does, but it's a blunt workaround if you don't know what exactly happens

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution has been found. In order to fix this issue, I stringified the store value and parsed the value using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse methods. This will disable the reactivity of pinia store values.